# Unable to install Meson because of unmet dependencies, can't seem to fix?

Tags: debian, python

I'm running Debian 10, after very recently switching from Ubuntu. I'm trying to install Meson, but coming up with some errors. What am I doing wrong?

After cloning Meson, `python3 setup.py install` gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Installing setuptools:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 33.1.1-1) but 40.8.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried fixing missing packages

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
Ign:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch Release
```

Tried installing python3-pkg-resources

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pkg-resources
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pkg-resources is already the newest version (40.8.0-1).
python3-pkg-resources set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

At this point I'm completely clueless. It's clear I'm not understanding something important. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--
Edit:
After trying `pip3 install meson` I received a traceback error.

```
$ pip3 install meson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Comment: does `pip3 install --upgrade pip` solve your situation?

Comment: Doing this gives me a traceback error ending in:

ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py)

Looks like I'm missing distutils?

Comment: does `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.7` fix it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` tells me:

`Package python3-distutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libpython3.7-stdlib`

Trying to install that, I get:

`libpython3.7-stdlib is already the newest version (3.7.3-2).
libpython3.7-stdlib set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Same with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.7`, already installed

Comment: python3-distutils certainly exists. Are you using really Debian 10 or a derivate like Kali?

Comment: I really am using Debian 10
`$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
`

Comment: There is something messed up or versions/repositories mixed then.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed issue. Updated sources.list, for some reason was using debian 9 repos. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip3: `pip3 install meson` will take care of everything

Comment: Doing so gives me a traceback error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py)

Thoughts?